# calling a c++ function with argument that is a reference to vector element

Tags: c++, recursion, vector, maze

I am writing a c++ program for solving maze (actually for maze solving line follower). For that I declared a global variable:

```
vector< node > node_container  // to contain each node encountered 
                              //  with its latest info.
```

where node is a class indicating actual node in maze .

```
class node 
{ 

 //members..

};
```

now i am using recursion to solve the maze using the function,

```
void node_action(node & current_node)      
// will be called with argument node_container[0] for the first time  
{

//do some works first...then

if(new_node_found == true)
{      
 node new_node;

 node_container.push_back(new_node);

 // i think at this point reference variable current_node becomes invalid     
// because the vector is just reallocated . am i correct ?

//here new node becomes current node and node_action() function is called for it now 

node_action(node_container[(node_container.size())-1]); 

//return to our first node i.e. for which this version of node_action() is called.       
// but i think 'current_node' is no more that what i want it to be 

}

} // end of node_action()     

int main()
{

 node first ;        
 node_container.push_back(first);      
 node_action(node_container[0]);

}
```

Now my question is if I am correct with the reference to element of vector node_container i.e. 'current_node' (i.e. it becomes invalid ), whats the way around of this problem?

One possible solution may be passing the argument by value, not by reference and update the node_container every time any node object is modified.

But this is really a messy way and I want to do it net and clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference may become invalid when the `vector` is resized.

Instead of passing in the reference to the node itself, it is safer to pass in the `vector` index to the current node.

```
void node_action(int current_node)      
{
    //...
    node_action(node_container.size()-1);

}

//...
node_action(0);
```

Then, to access the current node, you index into `vector` to do it.

Comment: thanks for your great answer @jxh...i also thought similar except that i wanted a to pass a copy of node only to extract its node_no and do every thing on the node_container[node_no]...what a dump i am !!!

Answer (score 2):

> I think at this point [after `push_back`] reference variable `current_node` becomes invalid, because the `vector` is just reallocated. Am I correct?

Yes, you are correct. The `vector` may or may not be reallocated, but since there is a possibility, you should consider the prior reference invalidated.

> What's the way around of this problem ?

If you pre-allocated enough elements upfront, or use a plain C array instead of a vector, the reference would remain valid. You must ensure that the capacity is sufficient for the worst-case scenario to run without re-allocations.

If you always access the elements sequentially, another solution could be using a linked list, because adding elements to a linked list do not change references to its existing elements.

Comment: thanks for your answer @dasblinkenlight... i have just learned a new thing about list...